# MySQL GROUP BY два условия

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

Есть таблица с тремя типами пользователей: user, moder, guest.
В поле reg условно обозначено значение регистрировался ли пользователь или нет(да/нет)

```
+--------+------+
| title  |  reg | 
+--------+------+
|  user  |  да  |
|  moder |  да  |
|  guest |  нет |
|  user  |  да  |
|  user  |  да  |
|  moder |  да  |
|  moder |  нет |
|  moder |  нет |
|  guest |  да  |
|  guest |  нет |
+----+----------+
```

Необходимо вывести таблицу , сгруппировав типы пользователей и посчитать сколько было зарегистрированных (regged), а сколько нет (notregged).

Итог должен быть примерно такой:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
| title  |  regged | notregged |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|  user  |    3    |     0     |
|  moder |    2    |     2     |
|  guest |    1    |     2     |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

Ниже запрос выведет только первые две колонки (title и regged), а как  подключить еще и третью?

```
SELECT `title`, COUNT(*) as regged FROM `table` WHERE `reg`='да' GROUP BY `title`
```

Comment: `SUM(reg='да')` и `SUM(reg='нет')` (или, скажем, `COUNT(*)-SUM(reg='да')`). А WHERE убрать нафиг.

Comment: Akina, премного благодарен. Все верно.